# Is the WSo2 agent needed in order to install an app from the Enterprise Store?

Tags: wso2, wso2-es, wso2-iot

Running 1.1.0 EMM package on Windows 2012R2.
I added some APKs to the Enterprise Store and have used an Android 4.4.2 and 5.1.1 tablets to browse the store.  I have selected to install an app. It links me to a signing page where I sign in.  It then jumps to a localhost URL which fails to do anything.  What am I missing? What step needs to be done? Does the WSo2 agent need to be installed on the device before the app install can be accomplished?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to have Android Agent installed in your phone in oder to install an app from the enterprise store. You need to configure your server before setting up EMM. 
see this link:  https://docs.wso2.com/display/EMM110/General+Server+Configurations